# Using local webpages as an interface in C#

Tags: c#

I have a couple of questions regarding a project I recently started working on. This project requires me to discover devices on the network (broadcasting UDP packets on a specific port), store device information into a database, and then display all the data on a local web page. My questions are:

1. Can I have a C# program that runs in the background that deals with the device discovery and database management while also running a local webpage for users to interact with?
2. If so, which kind of Visual Studio project would be the best to
   implement this project?
3. If not, how else could I do this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the welcome tour to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Unfortunately you're right that the question is too broad and opinion based to be of use.

Comment: (1) Of course, (2) there is no "best", but if you're doing a background process, that suggests a Windows service.

Comment: Look up on hosting WCF on a Windows Service, it's probably what you are looking for

Comment: I would go with a solution with 2 projects. One a Windows service that queries the devices and adds the data to the DB, and second an ASP.NET project that queries the DB and produces the user-facing web interface.

Comment: @Alejandro would I be able to (once both projects are done) have them as a single install or instance that I can run on different computers?

Comment: @Rookie you could certainly create an automated process which would build and deploy both projects to pre-defined target environments, yes. The separate user-interface (web app in your case) and background-windows-service (presumably with a shared data store) approach is certainly the standard solution to this kind of thing and has been since forever, but I have heard of an approach where you can embed a little web app within a windows service using OWIN, I'm not sure what's involved but that's something you could potentially investigate further if you wish.

Comment: Do you have to store these devices in a database.  What if you just looked them up upon request.  since you will be constantly looking them up why not just look them up when the user looks at the web page. You can make an MVC web page like a web service by using web api it will return a JSon object.

Comment: I would recommend leaving this open. A similar answer helped me in the past

Comment: @CharlesMcIntosh network device discovery can be time-consuming and of variable speed, not to mention the number of devices could be large and is also unknown. I would not recommend this as it's quite possible the webserver process would time out, or at least appear very slow to the user. Best for the page to display the most recently available results, while a background process is trying to discover the latest information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a problem where we needed a long running process that was initiated by a user but which timed out. We resolved this by running a background Windows service which interacted with the database backing the website. We also have other tasks that we wish to run asynchronously following user action. We run three Windows services on the web server; this solution has been running successfully for a number of years. So, in answer to our specific points:

1. Yes, as a Windows service separate from your website project
2. There is a specific project type for this; you will also need to set up an installation project
3. There may be other ways but I would recommend this approach

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this sounds like what I need to do as well! I have followup question, I'm fine with having a couple of services running at the same time, but I need a final solution to be under one executable and run under a single instance for my user. Would that be possible with multiple services?

Comment: "I need a final solution to be under one executable and run under a single instance" Why? What's wrong with two processes running? Don't forget as a web app and a service and database this should run on a server (or servers) anyway, not on a single user's machine. It's not clear why this gives you a problem? Given the number of processes usually executing on a windows O/S these days, adding two or three more doesn't really make much odds IMO.

Comment: The services can run as a single process. A separate solution is required for the web process

Comment: Maybe I was unclear with my follow up question. I'm fine with a couple of services running on a users machine, but I need to project to be executed from one single location. So could this multi-service program be launched from one single place?

Comment: @Rookie "services running on a users machine". Like I said, they should run on a server. If you're discovering and logging network devices, this goes on continuously in the background. It probably should not stop when a user shuts down their machine, and it should not interfere with performance of the user's laptop. And a web-app is also continuously available, so you don't need to "execute" the project. You just deploy the components (from Visual Studio or a build server, probably) and then the application is available to anyone whenever they need to use it.